# Fading edges/mask with animation in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I've created an animation that shows multiple cars driving upwards. The animation looks like the following image:

[Animated cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PePiD.png)

This animation needs to be placed on top of a Google Map fragment and the cars must be faded out at the top and bottom side.

Right now i got this working using keyframes and i manually created 15 images that are shown after each other to create this effect.

The problem is i rather just create the animation using an ObjectAnimator and making the fading edges in code so i can easily change the
picture of the car when i need to.

I tried to solve my problem using the following code:

```
public class MaskView extends View {
    private Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car);
    private float topStart = -bitmap.getHeight();
    private float top = 0; // Don't change!
    //private final float margin = Util.convertDpToPixel(5f, getContext());
    private final int smoothness = 10;
    private final float speed = bitmap.getHeight() / 20;
    private LinearGradient linearGradient = null;
    private Paint defaultPaint;
    private Paint maskPaint;
    private Path maskPath;

    public MaskView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int halfWidth = width / 2;
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        linearGradient = new LinearGradient(halfWidth, 0, halfWidth, height, new int[] {
                Color.parseColor("#00000000"), Color.parseColor("#CC000000"), Color.parseColor("#CC000000"), Color.parseColor("#00000000")}, new float[] {0f, 0.3f, 0.7f, 1f}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        defaultPaint = new Paint();
        defaultPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        defaultPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

        maskPaint = new Paint();
        maskPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        maskPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

        maskPaint.setShader(linearGradient);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        maskPath = new Path();
        maskPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        maskPath.lineTo(width, 0);
        maskPath.lineTo(width, height);
        maskPath.lineTo(0, height);
        maskPath.lineTo(0, 0);
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(topStart < 0f) {
                    topStart += speed;
                }
                else
                    topStart = -bitmap.getHeight(); // Reset

              invalidate();
              postDelayed(this, smoothness);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if(linearGradient == null) return;

       top = topStart;

        while(top < canvas.getHeight())
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, top, null);
            top += bitmap.getHeight();
        }

         canvas.drawPath(maskPath, maskPaint);
    }
}
```

This approach uses the ondraw method to draw the cars and uses a handler to move this cars 1px up at a certain interval. Then it uses a gradient filter to fade out the edges at the top and bottom of the view. The problem with this approach is that the animation doesn't seem to run smoothly.

Does anybody know a good solution to solve this problem? I can't use an image for the fading effect because the background is scrollable (Google Map).

Thanks!

Edit:

Replaced the Handler with an ValueAnimator. Animation seems to run smoother now but still feels like it's lagging a bit:

```
final ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-bitmap.getHeight() - margin, 0f);
va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
va.setDuration(smoothness);
va.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
va.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
a.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        topStart = value;
        invalidate();
    }
});
va.start();
```

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator` instead of `Handler`, the overall effect will be much better

Comment: Thanks, i updated my question

Comment: Sorry, i didnt notice its infinite animation, maybe TimeAnimator would be better?

Comment: TimeAnimator feels worse than a ValueAnimator. But maybe i am using it wrong.

Comment: strange,  i would bet my last pair of shoes that TimeAnimator will be better...

Comment: Can you send an example of how to use it correctly. I will update the question with my version.

Comment: try [this](http://pastebin.com/77b9kzgC)

Comment: Y thanks, works fine now! Can you make it an answer so i can accept it? Else i will edit my question.

Comment: sure, i made it an answer

Comment: Thanks, 1 more question can i use this pre JELLY_BEAN? Else i will just update my API version.

Comment: TimeAnimator was introduced in JELLY_BEAN so you need some support libs, http://nineoldandroids.com/ maybe?

Comment: Thanks! Edited your answer so other people know how to use this support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this simple implementation (you can adjust the speed in `onTimeUpdate` listener, now one car moves up per second):

```
public class MaskView extends View implements TimeAnimator.TimeListener {
    private Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car);
    private float y;
    private Paint carPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
    private Rect carRect = new Rect();

    public MaskView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        int colors[] = {0x00000000, 0xff000000, 0xff000000, 0x00000000};
        float[] positions = {0f, 0.3f, 0.7f, 1f};
        maskPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), h, colors, positions, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        carPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
        carRect.set(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), h + bitmap.getHeight());
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        TimeAnimator animator = new TimeAnimator();
        animator.setTimeListener(this);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, -y);
        canvas.drawRect(carRect, carPaint);
        canvas.translate(0, y);
        canvas.drawRect(carRect, maskPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
        y = (bitmap.getHeight() * totalTime / 1000f) % bitmap.getHeight();
        invalidate(carRect);
    }
}
```

Edit:

To use this pre JELLY_BEAN:

Gradle:
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+'

Class:
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.TimeAnimator;